# PDF preview in AIR

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, air

I'm trying to preview a PDF file into a Flex (AIR) application : I am using the mx.controls.HTML component and it works perfectly when I build my project into flex builder. But when exporting to a validated version : I can preview a web page but not a PDF file. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks,

Nicolas

Comment: Perhaps your window has transparent = true?

Comment: Apparently not... I really don't understand

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" creationComplete="init()" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<mx:HTML width="100%" height="100%" id="h" />

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var pdf:HTMLLoader;
        private function init():void
        {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.tagg.org/pdftest.pdf");
            pdf = new HTMLLoader();
            pdf.height = 800;
            pdf.width = 600;
            pdf.load(request);
            h.addChild(pdf);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
 </s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: I dont know this is not work for u, Ive perfectly work this. Im edit answer with full code. Pls copy and paste , then run this code.

Comment: I've just run your code, and it still doesn't work when exporting to a validating version... (it works when testing in flexbuilder)

Comment: how did u export to validating version?

Comment: In flex builder (V4.0.1) : project -> export to a validated version